# How to limit number of terms in for loop?

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

How would I go about using a value of user input to limit the terms in a for loop. The objective of the program is to let the user input the amount of terms, starting value, and counting interval. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is simple to answer by consulting [TIBasicDev](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com), specificly the pages for `Input`, `Prompt`, and `For(`. `Input` and `Prompt`  are self explanatory; they serve as two means of retrieving input from the user. `For(` can take arguments to exhibit the behaviors you want.

## [`Prompt`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/prompt)

`Prompt` is smaller and dirtier. The program

```
Prompt A
```

will result in the following output.

```
A=?
```

---

## [`Input`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/input)

`Input` is the larger and cleaner option. The program

```
Input "ENTER VALUE:",A
```

will result in the following output

```
ENTER VALUE:
```

---

## [`For`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/controlflow#toc7)

Taken from TIBasicDev:

> The For loop takes four arguments: the variable (A-Z or theta), the starting value, the ending value, and the increment. It counts from the starting value to the ending value at the specified increment.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Format
> :For(variable,start,end[,increment])
> :Command(s)
> :End
> ```

---

Writing your program will now simply require using the input commands to retrieve user input then using the for loop to create the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

As dohaqatar7 said, you can achieve your goal using the basic input commands. However, there is also a (slightly more advanced) way to allow users to input the values all at once, separated by commas. To do this, you input a string, store it into a built-in string variable like `Str1`, then convert it to a list of numbers, and finally access each element of the list for the parameters in your `For(` loop.

```
Input "START,END,STEP: ",Str1        //Whatever is input goes into Str1 as a string
                                     //For example, "1,100,2"
expr("{"+Str1                        //Then it is converted into a list like {1,100,2}
For(X,Ans(1),Ans(2),Ans(3)           //Evaluates to For(X,1,100,2
[your code]
End
```

`expr(` means expression, and basically tells the calculator to evaluate the string passed to it. But first, a `{` is tacked on to the front so the calculator interprets it as a list, which is stored into the Ans variable. Individual elements of a list are accessed in the format [listname] (position), so `Ans(1)` will get the first element of the list (in this case the start value 1) and so on.